# How to DumpSave previously assigned symbols

Tags: evaluation, symbols, dumpsave

I'm trying to `DumpSave[]` some variables based on their name string. To define them, I'm using

```
assignValueFromVariableName = Function[{string, value}, Clear[string]; Evaluate@Symbol[string] = value];
```

which allows me to define and assign a variable from a string. For example,

```
assignValueFromVariableName["foo", 1]
```

yields

```
In[]:= foo

Out[]= 1
```

However, once it's assigned, I can no longer `DumpSave` it from it's name. To be clear,

```
DumpSave["foo.mx", foo]
```

works properly but

```
DumpSave["foo.mx", Symbol["foo"]]
```

does not, since the symbol is evaluated first.

I've tried using `Hold[]`, `HoldForm[]` and `Unevaluated[]` but to no avail so far. Is it possibly to save the symbol **only by using it's name string?**

Also, I've found a workaround with `Put[]`, but it was significantly slower. I'd like to preserve `DumpSave[]` fast behaviour. Is this possible? If so, how?

**Edit**

As Carl Woll mentioned,

```
DumpSave["foo.mx","foo"]
```

does work in this simplified example. However, in my original code, I'm using this function to generate the names:

```
generateSolutionName[bOverbMax_, velocity_, \[Alpha]_] := Module[{},
"solvInf"
<> ToString[velocity*10^-3]
<> "b0p"
<> StringExtract[
ToString[NumberForm[FractionalPart[bOverbMax], 32]], "." -> 2]
<> "alpha"
<> ToString[\[Alpha]]
]
```

which produces something like `solvInf5b0p5alpha0`. I've confirmed that the output of this function is indeed a string (just like "foo"), but if I try

```
DumpSave["foo.mx", generateSolutionName[0.5, 5*10^3, 0]]
```

I get the following error:

```
DumpSave::bsnosym: generateSolutionName(0.5,5 10^3,0) is not defined as a symbol or a context.
```

This is why I was trying to use `Symbol[]` in my original simplified example.

**Edit II**

Apparently, if I write

```
DumpSave["foo.mx", Evaluate@generateSolutionName[0.5, 5*10^3, 0]]
```

it works just fine. However, I came to this merely by experience (like when you have to use `Evaluate` before a `Table` inside `Plot`. If someone could explain why this works, I'd appreciate it. Sorry if it's something basic that I've overlook.

Comment: Did you try using `DumpSave["foo.mx", "foo"]`?

Comment: Well, I did with my original code. Strangely enough, your proposal works in this simplified example, but not on the original. I'll edit the question to try to provide more information.

Comment: DumpSave has the HoldRest attribute. This is why you need the Evaluate.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thank you! Not sure how to close this though... If you'd turn your comment into an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.